# JsPDF in Angular 5 addImage() method

Tags: html, angular, jspdf

i am using jspdf library for converting my html into pdf

html :

```
 <div *ngFor="let person of people"
             {{person.name}}
            <button (click) = "generatePdf()"></button>
         </div>

         <div id="contentForPdf" style="display:none">
            <div *ngFor="let person of people">
                {{person.address}}
            </div>
     </div>
```

in component :

```
public generatePdf():void{
              const data = document.getElementById('contentForPDF');
                 html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
                   const imgWidth = 300;
                   const pageHeight = 295;
                   const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
                   const heightLeft = imgHeight;
                   const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                   const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
                   const position = 0;
                   pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth,imgHeight);
                   pdf.save(name);
                   }
```

and because of display is none addImage method is giving me error as :

1. Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: addImage does not support files
   of type 'UNKNOWN', please ensure that a plugin for 'UNKNOWN' support
   is added. Error: addImage does not support files of type 'UNKNOWN',
   please ensure that a plugin for 'UNKNOWN' support is added.

Comment: I don't want to print person's address on screen and want it in only pdf. Any help is  appreciated ...

Comment: "I learned that I shouldn't try to use the image but use dataURI.
I converted my image to a dataURI using this website:
https://websemantics.uk/tools/image-to-data-uri-converter"-dapperAuteur

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/png_support/zlib.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/png_support/png.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.png_support.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>
```

**TS**

```
   const doc = new jsPDF();
   const imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAABy...
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 50, 50, 50, 50);
    doc.output('pdf-img');
```

Comment: got the solution as I am hiding the whole div after pdf.save('myPdf'); and showing it as $('#id').show(); before save method . Thanks Patricio Vargas for your time ...

Comment: @chaitanya How to solve if using display:none property...any help is appreciated bro